# Ruby controller for layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing a `ip_to_geo` function for my blog. I attach a function in the layout. My `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<header>
  <span>the geo_span I used to show ip_to_geo result</span>
</header>

<%= yield :articles %>

<footer>
</footer>
```

and in my `articles_controller.rb`, I have code like this:

```
def index
  ip_to_geo_in_controller
end
```

I put the `geo_string` to the span in `welcome.coffee` every time the page is updated.

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  update_geo_span()
```

I have a lot of article lists that share the same layouts, and every time I change the list, `ip_to_geo_in_controller` in the controller runs.

I wish there is some way to let `ip_to_geo_in_controller` only run once when my layout is loaded.

I tried to create `app/controllers/layouts_controller.rb`, and put the following code in it. But this controller is not loaded when the layout (`/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`) is loaded.

```
def application
  ip_to_geo_in_controller
end
```

Comment: Thanks @sawa for correcting my question.

Answer (score 4):

If I properly understood what you want to achieve, caching might help you:

```
def index
  @cached_ip ||= ip_to_geo_in_controller
end
```

That way the value is calculated and stored in `@cached_ip` instance variable unless it is already cached.

Comment: This "cache" won't survive page reload, though.

Comment: Yes, that is true. More sophisticated caching, involving `Rach::Cache` or similar mechanisms is out of scope of this question, I think.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your method and put a put a line puts "this should only show once" in ip_to_geo_in_controller function, and run this in production environment. And "this should only show once" is still printed when I change my article list.

Comment: Okey, I will try to figure out how to cache it.

Answer (score 0):

The layout is rendered once per page, as already mentioned by @Sergio Tulentsev.

If you want to change the contents without reloading the page, this is one of the use cases for XHR/Ajax/asynchronous calls. The calls would just fetch the article list and render it inside the browser.

Doing so, the `ip_to_geo_in_controller` happens only once when processing `articles#index`. And no caching problem to solve...

### Update

A Sample minimalistic don-t-use-as-is implementation.

#### Layout View

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="geo"><%= @ip_to_geo %></p>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Application Controller

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :ip_to_geo

  private
  def ip_to_geo
    @ip_to_geo = [ 'You are here', '123.4.5.6' ].sample
  end
end
```

#### Article View

`app/views/articles/index.html.erb`

```
<h1>Articles</h1>
<ul id='articles'>
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <li><%= article %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<button id='update_articles'>Update</button>

<script>
  document.getElementById('update_articles')
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
      var update = new XMLHttpRequest();
      update.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        var new_list = JSON.parse(event.target.response).articles;
        var list = document.getElementById('articles');
        while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
          list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < new_list.length; i++) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new_list[i]));
          list.appendChild(li);
        }
      });
      update.open("GET", "/articles.json");
      update.send();
    });
</script>
```

#### Articles Controller

`app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = [ [:a1], [:a2, :a3], [:a4, :a5, :a6] ].sample
  end
end
```

#### Route

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/articles' => 'articles#index'
end
```

### Notes

- Demo:

  - If you reload the page of this sample, both location and article lists will change, for demonstration purpose.
  - If you press the update button, only the article list is reloaded. The location field stays still, until the whole page is reloaded.
- The articles and application controller returns dummy article and location data at random, so that each call may show some change.
- The XHR implementation is raw. We would usually rely on a framework.
- Tested on Firefox only, but it did work.
- I left out a Jbuilder template for the `/articles.json` route.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to put the ip_to_geo_in_controller function in the browser-side. I tried this though, like the following code:

    $.ajax "#{Settings.link.local_freegeoip}#{ipAddress}",
          type: 'GET'
          dataType: 'html'
          error: () ->
               # do nothing
          success: () ->
               json = JSON.parse(data)
               alert "#{json['country_name']}, #{json['city']}"

Comment: But there are certain reason why I don't put this code in browser-side. for instance browser-side can't access local freegeoip database. But I still think there should be a solution following your idea, is there any eclectic way to get this? Like let the back-end do database access only once and let the browser change the span contain permanently.

Comment: I meant the IP2Geo part remains in the controller-generated (server-side) code. XHR is used only to refresh the articles list from the browser.

Comment: My answer is too abstract---sorry. I am away now but I will provide details later, unless someone else gets the idea and answers :-)

Comment: You mean XHR/Ajax is for article update? In my blog application, they are controlled by articles_controller the controller will get article list based on article type and deliver it to .erb via instance variable, it's not Ajax right now, but it would be a good idea. I'm implementing a cache system to as Sergio Tulentsev and mudasobwa said. But I will try your answer when you comeback. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Eric Platon, I already did it with cache. But if you still want to teach me a way with ajax to article list, I would like to learn and definitely would try it. Thanks.